# Laravel: how to reference javascript function with blade syntax defined in public/app.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have an ajax call that has some blade templating inside. This ajax call is used repeatedly over multiple views. I would like to define it once and link to it in each view but I get errors due to blade syntax. What can I do so I only have it defined in one place?

**/public/myapp.js**

```
//checkbox validation
    $(document).ready(function(){
    //Check age and display dialog box to over-ride age if administrator
    $('input:checkbox').click(function(e) {
        if( $(this).prop('checked') &&  $(this).val()=='on' )
        {
            e.preventDefault();

            var name = $(this).attr('name');
            var pivot_attendee_program = name.split(/\]\[|\[|\]/);
            var data = {
                        'pivot' : pivot_attendee_program[0],
                        'attendee_id' : pivot_attendee_program[1],
                        'program_id' : pivot_attendee_program[2]
                       };
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: '{{ route('ageCheck') }}',
                    data: data,
                    context: this,
                    success: function(result){
//...code goes on but is irrelevant
```

I get error

```
Error: SyntaxError: missing } after property list
Source Code:
                    url: '{{ route('ageCheck') }}',
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just use PHP code (that's what Blade essentially is) in JavaScript files. A simple workaround for this problem is to inject the route url as a JavaScript variable.

*This has to be inside a blade file (usually your layout)*

```
<script>
    var ageCheckUrl = '{{ route('ageCheck') }}';
</script>
```

And then you can use that variable in your external JS files:

```
type: "GET",
url: ageCheckUrl,
data: data,
context: this,
```